# Accessing DispHTMLElementCollection properties

Tags: html, xml, vba, excel

I need to iterate through the elements of an object that (as the debugger states) is a `DispHTMLElementCollection`.

Can't seem to be able to access the properties of a `DispHTMLElementCollection` as there is a table with 50 `td` tags on this page, and when I print out the length of this object it returns `0`.

Any light about this is appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Using this snippet, you still need to break the code to press the search button to show some results, but after that, still returns `zero` as length...

```
Dim objHTML As HTMLDocument

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
With ie
    .navigate "https://www.oeko-tex.com/en/manufacturers/certified_products/certified_products.html"
    .Visible = True
    While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
       DoEvents
    Wend
    Set objHTML = .document
    DoEvents
End With
Set elementONE = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("td")
Debug.Print TypeName(elementONE)
Debug.Print elementONE.Length
```

Comment: Easier if you can post the code you're using and show how you get this collection in the first place.

Comment: I don't see any tables on that page.

Comment: Try search with random criteria so that results show up, and the table is created...

Comment: The results table is in a page hosted in an iframe, so it's not the same document as the one you have a reference to in your code...

Comment: Can you tell me how to access it?

Comment: It has an id, so presumably you can use something like `objHTML.getElementById("id_here").document.getElementsByTagName("td")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the feedback from Tim Williams

```
Sub test()

    Dim objHTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim oElemets As Object
    Dim oElement As Object

        Dim h As HTMLOptionElementFactory
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .navigate "https://www.oeko-tex.com/en/manufacturers/certified_products/certified_products.html"
        .Visible = True
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Wend
        Set objHTML = .document
        DoEvents
    End With

    ' As per the suggestion Tim Williams proposed
    Set objHTML = objHTML.getElementById("customer-profile")
    Set oElemets = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("td")


    For Each oElement In oElemets
        Debug.Print oElement.nodeName
    Next

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: You are welcome but all the credit goes to Tim Williams for his Html DOM knowledge.